# How do I separate 1 column "0.1.2 Contaminated land" to 2 columns "0.1.2" & Contaminated land" (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following column in pandas

| Code |
| --- |
| 0.1.2 Contaminated land |
| 1.1.1 Standard foundations (default) |
| 1.1.2 Specialist foundations |
| 8.1.2 Preparatory groundworks |

How do I separate it into the following below?

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0.1.2 | Contaminated land |
| 1.1.1 | Standard foundations (default) |
| 1.1.2 | Specialist foundations |

[image]

using the following code I get the below, which does not work.

```
df[['code', 'description']] = df['code'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `.str.split()` with `1` as the split count and `expand=True` to expand into series](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split), then assign back to your df.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"code": [
    '0.1.2 Contaminated land',
    '1.1.1 Standard foundations (default)',
    '1.1.2 Specialist foundations',
    '8.1.2 Preparatory groundworks',
]})

df[['code', 'description']] = df['code'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
print(df)
```

```
    code                     description
0  0.1.2               Contaminated land
1  1.1.1  Standard foundations (default)
2  1.1.2          Specialist foundations
3  8.1.2         Preparatory groundworks
```

Comment: Thanks, strangely it worked for some columns but no others, I've add the image response in the question

Comment: Chances are the separator is not the regular space, but eg. a nonbreaking space. You could use the `\s+` regexp to split..?

Comment: I used the following s.str.extract('(?:(.*\d))?(?:([a-zA-Z]+))?', expand=True)     Thanks